# Using custom C++ code for a HTML5 project

Tags: javascript, c++, html

I've got a .cpp file that has a class and some functions that produce a desired output. However, our project is being written in HTML5/PHP. My question is, can I take input from the HTML source, use my C++ code to generate some output, and send it back to the HTML to be used for display on the website? I've tried using emscripten to change my code into a .js file but the file it produces is 80k+ lines of code and nobody wants to deal with that. Is there a way I can get this to work or am I doomed to having to rewrite my C++ code in js for this project?

Answer (score 0):

So, as with any language you can use it to run a server side solution to which the client can connect. With C++ you would thus have to look at something like [these frameworks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53625/50636). The downside to that is that it requires an internet connection and a special server installation.

On the html5/client side you're indeed right that you could use Emscripten. 80k+ lines of code doesn't really say much without knowing what the original code did and how long that one was. If it was *significantly* shorter then you should look into all the flags for Emscripten, because you might have included code that never gets triggered (or some of your code might have triggered the inclusion of a full file system emulation module, despite you not needing that). Do however understand that you would never edit the code generated by Emscripten directly! That's not how Emscripten is intended, nor is it advisable for the simple reason that the code isn't meant to be readable, nor sensible. The only thing the code should be is fast and runnable.